# SQL left join multiple tables join performance issue while I change the order

Tags: sql, performance, netezza

I am using netezza and I have a use case where I am doing left join betweeen 3 tables. Below are my SQL queries

```
-- FAST query (finishes in <3 secs): Join order a<-b<-c 
select a.asof_date, a.sfl_fs_perm_id,
    b.jobsactive, b.jobscreated, b.jobsremoved,
       c.aqe_sector_code
from DBS_E474947..TEMP_UNIV a
       left join DBS_E474947..TEMP_JOBS b
        on a.asof_date=b.asof_date and a.factset_entity_id=b.factset_entity_id  
       left join DBS_E474947..TEMP_REFERENCE c
        on a.asof_date=c.asof_date and a.sfl_fs_perm_id=c.sfl_fs_perm_id
limit 100;

-- SLOW query (takes 400+ secs): Join order a<-c<-b
select a.asof_date, a.sfl_fs_perm_id,
    b.jobsactive, b.jobscreated, b.jobsremoved,
       c.aqe_sector_code
from DBS_E474947..TEMP_UNIV a
       left join DBS_E474947..TEMP_REFERENCE c
        on a.asof_date=c.asof_date and a.sfl_fs_perm_id=c.sfl_fs_perm_id  
       left join DBS_E474947..TEMP_JOBS b
        on a.asof_date=b.asof_date and a.factset_entity_id=b.factset_entity_id  
limit 100;
```

Also size

```
SELECT count(1) FROM DBS_E474947..TEMP_UNIV  --36152447
SELECT count(1) FROM DBS_E474947..TEMP_REFERENCE --422341884
SELECT count(1) FROM DBS_E474947..TEMP_JOBS -- 73715474
```

Can someone help me understand why the second query is taking time? I know its because the TEMP_REFERENCE table has lot of records compared to other two. But whats the underlining logic behind this drastic change?

Query plan if it helps
--FASTER TABLE
Limit (cost=1758.5..1758.5 rows=100 width=53 conf=0)
l: Hash Join(left outer) (cost=1758.5..1205219.9 rows=283667616751 width=53 conf=33)
l: Hash Join(right outer) (cost=211.8..1356.1 rows=36152447 width=49 conf=51)
l: Sequential Scan table "B" (cost=0.0..794.9 rows=73715474 width=46 conf=80)
r: Hash (cost=211.8..211.8 rows=36152447 width=27 conf=0)
l: Sequential Scan table "A" (cost=0.0..211.8 rows=36152447 width=27 conf=100)
r: Hash (cost=1546.7..1546.7 rows=422341884 width=21 conf=0)
l: Sequential Scan table "C" (cost=0.0..1546.7 rows=422341884 width=21 conf=80)(FACT)

--SLOWER TABLE
Limit (cost=58492.0..58492.0 rows=100 width=53 conf=0)
l: Hash Join(left outer) (cost=58492.0..1628262.7 rows=62717563532 width=53 conf=33)
l: Hash Join(left outer) (cost=1546.7..1203983.1 rows=36152447 width=31 conf=51)
l: Sequential Scan table "A" (cost=0.0..211.8 rows=36152447 width=27 conf=100)
r: Hash (cost=1546.7..1546.7 rows=422341884 width=21 conf=0)
l: Sequential Scan table "C" (cost=0.0..1546.7 rows=422341884 width=21 conf=80)                               (FACT)
r: Hash (cost=794.9..794.9 rows=73715474 width=46 conf=0)
l: Sequential Scan table "B" (cost=0.0..794.9 rows=73715474 width=46 conf=80)

Comment: *why the second query is taking time?* LEFT JOIN fixes the tables scanning order (similar to STRAIGHT_JOIN). So there is no indices which will improve 2nd query simply. PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense. PPS. Do you **really** need in **LEFT** joining?

Comment: The question which deals with the performance must contain complete CREATE TABLE scripts and complete EXPLAIN output for all tables and queries.

Comment: First of all: drop the ‘limit 100’ when measuring performance.  The results may not be consistent with the ‘full’ result set.

Comment: Secipond comment: what are the 3 tables distributed on ? In particular  the TEMP_REFERENCE ? Perhaps switch it to or from RANDOM …. Does that help ?

Comment: Removed limit and its same. TEMP_REFERENCE is random, JOBS is random but TEMP_UNIV is factset_entity_id, asofdate which is part of the join

Comment: Now I made all the tables random distribution but still the same